# Changing the subject - more than one answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Make $x$ the subject of
>
> $5(x+2y)=p(2x-3)$

My textbook says that it doesn't matter which side you move the $x$ terms to when solving the problem, but if I put the $x$ terms over to the right-hand side, the answer becomes:

$\frac{10y+3p}{2p-5} = x$

Conversely, if I move them over to the left-hand side, the answer becomes:

$x = \frac{3p-10y}{5-2p}$

Are both answers correct?

Comment: Those are incompatible.  I expect you have made an arithmetic error.  Note, in general, that $\frac {a-b}{c-d}=\frac {b-a}{d-c}$.

Answer (score 3):

You have $$5(x+2y)=p(2x-3)$$

$x$ to LHS we get:

$$5x+10y=2px-3p$$ $$5x-2px=-3p-10y$$ $$x(5-2p)=-3p-10y$$ $$x=\frac{-3p-10y}{5-2p}$$ $$\boxed{x=\frac{10y+3p}{2p-5}}$$

$x$ to RHS we get:

$$5x+10y=2px-3p$$ $$10y+3p=2px-5x$$ $$10y+3p=x(2p-5)$$ $$\boxed{\frac{10y+3p}{2p-5}=x}$$

Be careful with the signs.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't really matter what side $x$ is on. $x=\frac{-3p-10y}{5-2p}$ is the correct answer, so you should probably check your working. Be careful when working with signs - it can lead to wild answers! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

$5(x+2y)=p(2x-3)$

$\iff 5x+10y=2px-3p$

$\iff 2px-5x=10y+3p$

$\iff x(2p-5)=10y+3p$

$\iff x=\frac{10y+3p}{2p-5}$

**Method 2**

$5(x+2y)=p(2x-3)$

$\iff 5x+10y=2px-3p$

$\iff 5x-2px=-3p-10y$

$\iff x=\frac{-3p-10y}{5-2p}$

**Key Observation**

These two answers are the same. Notice that:

$\frac{-3p-10y}{5-2p}$ = $\frac{-1}{-1}$($\frac{10y+3p}{2p-5})$=$\frac{10y+3p}{2p-5}$

Therefore, answer (1) is the same as answer (2), and so this is consistent with you being taught that we are able to rearrange for x in any way that you want.